# problem with @include file in template (laravel)

Tags: include, laravel-6.2

I'm trying to include many files to a blade file with dfr lang

```
@include("frontend.{$config->template}.privacy.Privacy-en")
@include("frontend.{$config->template}.privacy.Privacy-es")
@include("frontend.{$config->template}.privacy.Privacy-de")
.
.
.
```

I want one of these files to be imported according to the language chosen by the visitor

So I wrote this code as follows in **page.blade.php**

```
@include("frontend.{$config->template}.privacy.{'Privacy-' . LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()}")
```

The error:

```
No hint path defined for [frontend.nova.privacy.{'Privacy-'. LaravelLocalization]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\templates\frontend\nova\page.blade.php)
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is don't do it this way. Laravel has built-in support for localisation, so there is no need to build different pages for each language and then jump through hoops - as you are trying to do - to try and incorporate  the relevant one.

Read [the documentation about localisation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization) - in short, set up one blade template (called 'privacy.blade.php' for example) and within it use short keys such as :

```
{{ __('privacy.introduction') }}
```

and then define those keys within the relevant language files (so resources/lang/en/privacy.php, /fr/privacy.php, and so on) :

```
return [
    'introduction' => 'The following statements set out our privacy information',
];
```